# Upolad image files in background with a web worker in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, web-worker

I need the feature to be able to upload image files in background without making the user wait till all the files are uploaded. I want to use a web worker to do so but don't know how will the formdata of the images to be uploaded will be sent to the `worker.js`.

While the upload takes place the user should also be able to move around the we page and simultaneously the upload is also taking place. How to do this? I understand the basic of how the worker work and how to communicate with worker but I don't know how to send data to the worker for some work to be done in background.

Comment: is there a reason why you specifically wanted to use Web Worker when it is completely doable with AJAX?

Comment: yes because large file will be uploaded and the user will have to wait a lot if it takes more time to upload

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous/non-blocking so the user don't have to wait.

Comment: @IVOGELOV That’s completely incorrect: there is no requirement that `fetch` and/or `XMLHttpRequest` requests be sequential nor serial: on the contrary: you _can_ fire-off concurrent requests, even multiple requests to the same host ([the per-host connection limit is now 6, not 2 like it used to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser)) and you can await some or all using `Promise.all` and `Promise.race`. Nor does any pending or incomplete request block the user’s page navigation.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to use `readAsArrayBuffer` to transfer the file contents to a web worker - and then use a normal XHR or Fetch request:

```
 const fr = new FileReader();
 fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
 fr.onloadend = heap => this.worker.postMessage({
     command: 'TransferProfile',
     data: {
         heap
     }
 }, [heap]); //Passing [heap] as a 2nd parameter flags it as Transferable
```

If your files are really large (so reading them in RAM is not feasible) - you may find the [Resumable.js](http://www.resumablejs.com/) more suitable for your case.